# How to declare a typescript property on Obect prototype that returns the same type as the object instance

Tags: typescript

I add this property to my Object prototype:

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    // how can i declare that the result is not just any 
    // but the very same type as the object instance?
    get stripped(): any 
  }
}
```

Instead of returned any I would like to declare that the object type returned by stripped is the very same as the object instance. How can I do that?

Not overly relevant, but this property removes all properties that have the value undefined.

Comment: I would suggest you to avoid to use `Object` as your interface name, it could be confuse with `object` type

Comment: This *is* Object, I am extending the prototype, made that more clear with declare global. No need to address the controversy on that here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the this parameter:

```
stripped<T>(this: T): T,
```